# NSDictionary objectForKey is returning nil value

Tags: objective-c

I have a dictionary like this

```
123456
{
   "aaa"
   "aaav"
}
```

But when i try to get these values in `NSArray` using `objectForKey`, I am getting `nil`.

The key I am using is a string.

Code :

```
NSArray *arr = [userdetails objectForKey:str]
```

Where userdetails is an `NSDictionary` and str is `NSString` which contains the key.

Comment: Please `NSLog` the values of `str` and `userdetails` before the `objectForKey:` call, and show the details produced by the logger.

Answer (score 8):

`NSDictionary` cannot contain `nil` objects. There are two possibilities to get a `nil` back from `objectForKey`:

- Your dictionary itself has not been initialized, or
- There is no object for the key that you have specified.

Please make sure that you have created an instance of your `NSDictionary` or a compatible class (say, `NSMutableDictionary`) and assign it to the variable prior to querying it for the key. Then make sure the key in question contains an object.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the note, this is now fixed. An ability to edit answers is a great feature :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but when I used allkey I an getting that key in my array , but when I used that to find object I am getting nil.

Comment: @xxx Please edit the question to show the code that accesses the key.

Comment: I had the same problem, it is because sometimes the debugger doesn't work properly if the scheme is run on the release mode. Go to Edit Scheme > Run > Build Configuration and change it to Debug

Comment: Although it does not apply to the code in this question, there is a third way for -objectForKey: to return nil, even when passed one of the keys returned by -allKeys.  Such unexpected nil results may occur if the dictionary keys are not NSString objects, but are instead some custom object for which the developer has not properly implemented -isEqual: and/or -hash.